# Energy loss through bathtub drain

Tags: plumbing, energy-efficiency, heat

I noticed that there is significant heat loss at my bathtub drain.  If I put my hand above the bathtub drain, I feel an icy draft.

The plumbing is directly under the bathroom, in an unfinished basement.

Here's what I have thought of so far:

- Put a stopper in the bathtub when not bathing
- Put foam sleeves around the pipes in the basement
- Perhaps something in the plumbing arrangement in the basement needs to be re-done in some way

Any thoughts?

P.S. I chose "energy efficiency" as a tag because I couldn't find "heat loss."

---

Update: I nosed around downstairs while the hot water was running in the bathtub, so I could be sure I was looking at the correct pipe.  There is a U a little below where the pipe comes out of the bathtub.  Then there's a straight stretch of approximately 6 feet.  Then there's a T and the upper part goes up and out of the house.  That portion feels very cold.  So apparently I feel a cold draft at the bathtub drain because cold air from outside is coming in through that pipe!  Is that unorthodox?

---

Second update: Can I use "dryer vent seal"?  I found a [type that is sold at the DIY stores](https://www.walmart.com/ip/P-tec-Products-Inc-4-Tan-No-Pest-Vent-NPVT/38470613?athcpid=38470613&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=PWVUB&athieid=v0&athstid=CS020&athguid=bdaa6e7c-8bb-16941efdd3fa94&athena=true) and also a [homemade one](https://youtu.be/rRWneVA1vYA).

---

Third update: I read about the "AAV" but wasn't sure if I was on the right track.

Then I read about what might be my situation:

https://www.houselogic.com/organize-maintain/home-maintenance-tips/biggest-air-leak-home/

> 1. Crawl under your bathroom to look at the drain assembly from underneath.
> 2. Patch the hole with pieces of foam board that’s cut to fit around the pipes. Screw them in place.
> 3. Then seal any gaps with spray foam insulation ($8 per can).

Comment: Is there an air vent anywhere on top of a drain pipe in the basement?

Comment: @MikeWaters - Not sure.  I will try to figure that out.  Suggestions on how to go about that?  Also -- what will you say if the answer is yes, and what will you say if the answer is no?  I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with DIY stuff yet.

Comment: Is there a floor drain in the unfinished basement? If so, the water in the trap may have evaporated.

Comment: @MikeWaters - Yes.  There's a sump pail and a sump pump. // I feel like your comments should be able to help me figure this out but unfortunately I am not able to apply them -- I need things more step by step with lots of explanation.  Hope you can flesh out what you've said.

Comment: do you hear any sounds coming out of the drain?

Comment: Sounds like your drain pipes should be frozen, what keeps all the pipes down there from freezing? And if air's coming up out of the drain, does it smell like sewer gases?

Comment: @Xen2050 - No, it doesn't smell bad.  I think the pipes don't freeze because the basement is kind of like a root cellar.  It never gets down to a freezing temperature there.  Just now it is 27 degrees F outside and about 48 in the basement, for example.

Comment: @jsotola - No sounds.

Comment: Maybe there's another vent down there somewhere, could try following the drain pipes & see where they go... Any other drains have air coming up? Try plugging that drain & overflow and see if the air just redirects up another drain, maybe they house is sealed well but the furnace is forcing air outside without enough air coming back in the normal input vent (if there is one) so it's going in the regular plumbing vent & eventually inside

Comment: @Xen2050 - Did you see my update?  I think I identified the problem; but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Just reading the update now, sounds like the air is going down the roof vent, around & inside the house... Is there an input vent for the furnace, is it working ok? Any obvious holes or leaks in the ceiling/roof (maybe around attic access or windows or lights) that might be letting hot air out the top, and thus pulling cold air in?

Comment: @Xen2050 - It doesn't go to the roof.  It lets out just above what I think is called the footing.

Comment: Your sewer's open under your house? So if you have a plugged sewer line, water won't stop flowing down your sink/toilet/tub but will start dumping sewage under your house? That doesn't sound good, that's why the vents are usually above any drains. There are drain vent caps, but they still let air in since you still want air to come into the vent so the drains work right, but at lest it might stop sewer gases from collecting under the house

Comment: @Xen2050 - No, sorry I gave you that impression.  No, it isn't.